# add a column into a matrix refereing to an external one R

Tags: r, dictionary, matrix, merge

I have a matrix estracted from an R mining code in this format ( a part from 4751 row)

```
Result
              p*          AOA2+   AOA2-
Elevated     AFP           99     81 
Peripheral   neuropathy    97.5   64.5 
Cerebellar   atrophy       89     NSb
Oculomotor   apraxia      51      NSb
```

and I have a xsl matrix that contains those informations

```
dictionary

ref          p*
6574        AFP          
4521     neuropathy    
1754       atrophy       
3332      apraxia
```

I want to merge the result matrix and the dictionary in a way that it adds the convenient `ref` to each `p*` . my expected result is like this:

```
ref          p*         AOA2+   AOA2-
6574        AFP           99     81           
4521     neuropathy     97.5   64.5   
1754       atrophy       89     NSb       
3332      apraxia       51      NSb
```

Stacked in here. I couldn't find any information from where I can start
Any help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(Result, dictionary, by  = "p*")
```

Comment: I applied your method but this error appears.. can you explain this for me.....     Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'character')"

Comment: Humm it looks like `Result` and `dictionary` are actually `matrix` and not `data.frame`. Is it true? If so, could you edit your question by providing the code to reproduce `Result` and `dictionary`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `base` you can try:

`merge(Result, dictionary)`

Comment: thank you. but this function merged all the columns of the two dataframes. It haven't merge with my wanted key column